# Как сделать минимальное количество запросов mysql

Tags: pdo, php_pdo, php, база-данных, mysql

Есть массив с id'шниками записей. Нужно в каждой этой записи сменить одно значение на 1.
Можно ли сделать это одним запросом или минимальным количеством запросов. Или придется делать отдельный запрос для каждой записи?
Использую PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//$db = new PDO(...);

/* Выполнение подготовленного запроса с использованием массива для IN выражения */
//$ids = array(...);
/* Создаем строку из знаков вопроса (?) в количестве равном количеству параметров */
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

/*
    В этом примере подготавливается запрос с достаточным количеством неименованных
    псевдопеременных (?) для каждого значения из массива $params. Когда запрос будет
    выполняться, эти знаки вопроса будут заменены на элементы массива. Это не то же
    самое, что использовать PDOStatement::bindParam(), где привязка осуществлялась по
    ссылке на переменную. PDOStatement::execute() связывает параметры по значению.
*/

$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET column='1' WHERE id IN ($place_holders)");
$query ->execute($ids);
```

Документация по **[execute](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php)**.

Answer (score 1):

Для обновления в любом случае придется использовать `update`. Если всех id десяток-другой, то нет никакого смысла что то придумывать. Но если id много (тысячи), то есть смысл сделать оптимизацию. К примеру, id можно отсортировать и поискать "диапазоны". И как результат, можно делать что то в виде

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=1
WHERE column2 > 10 and column2 < 100;
```

и такой запрос может убрать 89 запросов.

Также, очень хорошо использовать транзакции и сделать все модификации в одной транзакции. Мой опыт с SQLite показал, что явные транзакции увеличивают скорость вставки ( у меня это были вставки, но суть не поменяется сильно) до 100 и более раз.

Следующий этап - это индексы. Иногда, при большой модификации следует выключить на время индексы, все сделать и снова их включить. Но этим нужно пользоваться аккуратно. Один с вариантов, когда это хорошо работает - если есть таблица с миллионами записей и нужно удалить почти все. Перестройка индексов съедает много ресурсов. Но, этим способом нужно пользоваться только после серьезных тестов и четкого понимания ситуации.