# WHERE запрос с IN в Mysqli — как?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Привет всем.

В общем проблема следующая:
Есть запрос:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM Publication WHERE id in (?)');
    $query->bind_param('s', $field_cat);
    $query->execute();
```

Где `$field_cat = "1,2,4";`

Как я понял, благодаря `bind_param`, в запрос вставляется только `(1)`. И запрос выполняется не так, как хотелось.

Нашел несколько решений с `Safemysql`.
Я бы не хотел использовать эту библиотеку, так как уже поздно переписывать запросы. Не уже ли в `mysqli` нету нормального решения?

Возможно ли сделать запрос без `Prepared Statements`?

Comment: А зачем без `Prepared Statements` делать, если можно и с ними? Правда муторно немного, с PDO проще будет. Здесь почти все просто: вы указываете, что `field_cat` это строка, поэтому она вставляется как `IN ('1,2,4')`. Чтобы это исправить надо ровно столько `?`, сколько параметров и столько же `s` в `bind_param`. Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236395) (обратите внимание, что для `call_user_func_array` параметры должны быть переданы по ссылке)

Comment: @ВОРОН Спасибо за ответ, но количество значений может меняться...

Comment: А что мешает это программно сделать (через [`array_fill`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-fill.php) и последующий [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php))? По количеству переменных формируете нужный набор вопросиков и вызываете `bind` через [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php). Сейчас нет времени ответ расписать, если нормального ответа до вечера не дадут, тогда вечером пример приведу.

Comment: [Пример для PDO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284915), но формирование вопросиков подойдет и вам.

Comment: @ВОРОН Интересное решение, спасибо. Ссылка хорошо помогла. Но с вызовом `bind` через `call_user_func_array` мне не все понятно. Буду благодарен если приведете пример.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не уже ли в mysqli нету нормального решения?

Нет.
Если делать канонически, то есть байндить все переменные через плейсхолдеры, то у нас наберется [аккурат на экран кода!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870999/bind-multiple-parameters-into-mysqli-query/17874410#17874410)

Варианты  сделать запрос без Prepared Statements и вместо них слепить из жувачки какие-то костыли, разумеется, АБСОЛЮТНО не годятся. Какой смысл было переходить на mysqli, если продолжать говнокодить в стиле mysql_* из прошлого века?

Поэтому я бы рекомендовал все же использовать Safemysql. Тем более, что количество кода сократится минимум в 5 раз - там, где mysqli нужно 5 строчек, на Safemysql нужна будет только одна. Ради одного этого стоило бы переписать.

Чтобы не быть голословным. Возьмём простейший пример получения одной переменной из запроса. Без циклов, с единственным фетчем.
raw mysqli:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM Publication WHERE cat=?');
$query->bind_param('s', $field_cat);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($id);
$query->fetch();
```

safemysql:

```
$id = $db->getCol('SELECT id FROM Publication WHERE cat=?s');
```

Как я и говорил - 5 к 1. 
Если же нам нужно получить массив, то соотношение еще больше увеличивается, поскольку у mysqli код прибавляется, а у safemysql остается все так же одна строчка, только меняется вызываемый метод.

**Update.**
Кстати, есть вариант не переписывать весь код.
Safemysql можно подключить, используя существующее соединение mysqi, вот так:

```
$db = new SafeMySQL(['mysqli' => $mysqli]);
```

Таким образом, после соединения с mysql можно приинклюдить Safemysql, создать инстанс, и использовать его наряду с mysqli без каких бы то ни было лишних накладных расходов.

Таким образом искомый код сведется к

```
$ids = $db->getCol('SELECT id FROM Publication WHERE id IN (?a)', $field_cat);
```

(следует помнить, что для плейсхолдера `?a` нужно передавать массив, а не строку "1,2,4")

А в дальнейшем можно будет постепенно переписать и остальные запросы более оптимальным образом.

Comment: Про костыли в комментах - это в мою сторону? Ну так вы перечитайте их, я как раз предлагаю от prepared statements не уходить и сделать вариант примерно похожий на ответ по ссылке (немного с другой реализацией)

Comment: А в запрос написать замену всех `[^,]*` на `?`, а потом сделать split по `,` и для для каждого элемента массива вызвать bind_param?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но меня на данный момент не хватит чтобы переписывать запросы. Поэтому, пока что буду думать что-нибудь с mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, подготовленные запросы в mysqli сделаны настолько неудобно, что пользоваться ими не хочется.

Я предпочитаю использовать класс-обертку, который прячет от меня особенности конкретного расширения + добавляет вкусняшки вроде подстановки массива в IN().

Варианты работы с массивом для mysqli и PDO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause/29653461#29653461

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант можно решить сию проблему с помощью [sprintf](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php).

```
$formated = "SELECT
                id
            FROM
                Publication
            WHERE 1=1
                AND id in ('%1\$s')";
$query = sprintf( $formated, $field_cat );
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
```

Comment: У вас в условии IN ровно одна строчка

Comment: @--A Как вариант, но сильно ли это отличается от:
`$query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id FROM Publication WHERE id in ('.$field_cat.')');
$query->execute();`

Comment: @Денис, если вы гарантируете что в переменной всегда только числа, то можно и ваш вариант использовать, но в общем эта идея плохая - где-нибудь может бяка закрасться. В комменте к вопросу привел ссылку на пример формирования запроса, там осталось только биндинг правильно сделать

Comment: @ВОРОН Вообще мне приходит POST массив от checkbox-ов, при этом в базе данных у меня есть набор цифр, которые там могут быть.
Потом я делаю так: `$cat = array_intersect($arr_cat, $_POST['cat']);`. То есть в новый массив `$cat ` попадают только те значения из `$_POST['cat']`, которые уже есть в `$arr_cat` из БД. А потом уже из массива `$cat ` я делаю строку `$field_cat = "1,2,4";`. Думаю что этими действиями я могу гарантировать правильность переменной `$field_cat`. Как Вы считаете?